# how to hide table rows in 2 different tables selecting dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to hide the table rows when i select the dropdown option
In first table drop down is there.options are
1.current state
2.future state

If i select current state according to that the in 2nd and 3rd table rows should be show & hide.. for that i am using id for that tr..as current as well as future.

```js
< script >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#curfut").on("change",
      function() {
        $("#future").hide();
        $("#current").show();
      });


  }); < /script>
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id="curfut">
        <option value="select"></option>
        <option value="Current">current</option>
        <option value="Future">future</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <div id="current"
    <tr>
      <td>
        <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="REDITBlue" VALUE="REDITBlueY" required />Yes
        <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="REDITBlue" VALUE="REDITBlueN" />No
      </td>
    </tr>
    <div id="future">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="implementationplan" VALUE="implementationplanY" required />Yes
          <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="implementationplan" VALUE="implementationplanN" />No
        </td>
      </tr>
    </div>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <div id="current>
  <tr>
 <td>What is the potential Cognizant BI identified from this VSM?($MM)</td>     
 <td><input type=" text " name="clientBI " id="clientBI " required> </td>
</tr>
    </div>
```

Comment: FYI your HTML is invalid. `#current` is missing a closing `>`, you've got repeated `id` attributes which have to be unique, and you cannot have `div` elements as the child of a `table`. The latter two are the main cause of your problem

Comment: It seems you are using `id="current"` multiple times, __Identifiers in HTML must be unique__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need make some correction in your html and javascript.

i have prepare Demo. please check [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gj0tqf3z/)

Check out below code you might want something like this:

Note : initially both option will be enable. you can make changes according to your requirement.

**Html :**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id="curfut">
        <option value="select"></option>
        <option value="Current">current</option>
        <option value="Future">future</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="current">

    <tr>
      <td>
        <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="REDITBlue" VALUE="REDITBlueY" required />Yes
        <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="REDITBlue" VALUE="REDITBlueN" />No
      </td>
    </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="implementationplan" VALUE="implementationplanY" required />Yes
          <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="implementationplan" VALUE="implementationplanN" />No
        </td>
      </tr>


</table>

<table id="future">

  <tr>
    <td>What is the potential Cognizant BI identified from this VSM?($MM)</td>                  
    <td><input type="text" name="clientBI " id="clientBI " required> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript** :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#curfut").on("change",
      function() {
        if($(this).val()=="Current")        
        {
          $("#future").hide();
          $("#current").show();
        }
        else if($(this).val()=="Future")        

        {
          $("#future").show();
          $("#current").hide();
        }
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get value of dropdown and show/hide according to the selection. If `Current` is selected than show div with id `current` and if `Future` option is selected than show div with id `future`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#curfut").on("change",
      function() {
        if($(this).val()=="Current")        
        {
          $("#future").hide();
          $("#current").show();
        }
        else if($(this).val()=="Future")        

        {
          $("#future").show();
          $("#current").hide();
        }
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Id be unique in Html you used same id 'current' many times please be correct it down.

And your code be like for your context

```
$("#curfut").on("change",function(){
     var getId = $(this).find('options:selected').text();
     $('#current, #future').hide();
     $('#' + getId).show()
  });
```